# How do I translate a view page title?

Tags: views, 8, i18n-l10n

Is there a way to translate a view page title in Drupal 8? How can I achieve it, if it is possible?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Install the Multilingual modules in admin/modules

[image]

Go to admin/config/regional/language and add the new language

[image]

Go to edit your View and click in Translate

[image]

Then click in edit

[image]

And go to edit the title

[image]

Comment: Thx man! I did not have the module Configuration Translation enabled. This was needed for views translation.

Comment: @jeroen a pleasure, and good luck in your project ;-)

Comment: One of the multi language improvements in D8, right? Remember the struggle to do something equivalent in D7 ???

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens Yes, I agree with you.

Comment: i did it this way, but my title is not translated in the frontend ??

Comment: @jimi you always need to do the translation by yourself, did you did it? This will only enable the translation feature.

Comment: @AdrianCidAlmaguer  yes, i translated the views. But that had no result.
Now i translated it at admin/config/regional/translate and now it's working. Maybe i did some configuration wrong?

Comment: @jimi I don't know, but at least its working ;-)

Comment: Thanks so much for this