# Translate view header

Tags: views, 8, i18n-l10n

I add a simple text as view header but it is not exists in translatable text in admin/config/regional/translate.

In Drupal 7 we could even translate unformulated views header and footer with the following steps:

1. Go to admin/config/regional/i18n/strings
2. Check "full HTML" in "Translatable text formats" section
3. Go to admin/config/regional/translate/i18n_string
4. Click on *Refresh strings*

Has this feature been removed form Drupal 8? (I don't think so.)
How can I translate view header and footer simple text?

Comment: Plain Drupal 7 doesn't have any admin/config/regional/i18n/strings; that is added by the i18n module.

Comment: @kiamlaluno I mean with module.drupal 7 by default not support i18n

Comment: There is a thread, that explain config translation:
http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/189872/how-to-translate-the-views-page-title

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Enable *"Configuration Translation"* core module
2. Go to your view edit and you will see a *"Translate view"* tab
3. You'll find your language in the list there. Then click on *"Edit"*
   next to the language
4. Expand panels and you will find your header text under the *"Header"*
   panel

Comment: 5 years ago( when I asked the question) this option wasn't there ;). thank you for your answer. could be helpful for other guys.

Answer (score 1):

If my previous answer doesn't work fine. Try with this solution.

1. In view add new field "Custom text" (Click checkbox Exclude from display)
2. In "Custom text" add code like this

```
    <div class="custom-title-and-subtitle">
    <h2>{% trans %}Contact us{% endtrans %}</h2>
    <p>{% trans %}Please contact us for UFME Inquiries only. For vocations and prayer requests, contact the Franciscans in your area.{% endtrans %}</p>
    </div>
```

3. In view header add "Unfiltered text" field
4. Click checkbox "Use replacement tokens from the first row"
5. Add REPLACEMENT PATTERNS in my case {{ nothing }}
6. Clear cache
   And after that you will be able find text in user interface translation "admin/config/regional/translate"

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to use configuration for your language. Example [image]

Answer (score -1):

You can easy translate view header and footer text using the {% trans %} Twig tag in Drupal 8
Example:

```
{% trans %}
  Text for translate
{% endtrans %}
```

And after that you will be able find text in user interface translation "admin/config/regional/translate"