# How to translate Views exposed filters?

Tags: views, 8, i18n-l10n

I know you can translate a views title pretty easy as answered here: [How do I translate a view page title?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/189872/how-to-translate-the-views-page-title)

Unfortunately I can't find a way to translate exposed filters buttons and labels properly. Using Drupal's `User interface translation` does never index those strings. Is there any known way (other than preprocessing the view to display translatable markup programmatically)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Follow the procedure in the [linked answer](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/189910/47547), which is, install the module *Configuration Translation* and add a translation to your view. Then you'll find these translation options:

**EXPOSED FORM**

[image: Exposed form]

**FILTERS**

[image: Filters]

Comment: Where? How do you get there? I don't see any "CONTENT DEFAULT DISPLAY OPTIONS" using 8.2.8.

Comment: You have to go on the views overview and click on the arrow of the edit button of the respective view. There you chose Translate.