# Translate view (multilingual module)

Tags: views, 8, i18n-l10n

I have create view where it get an image banner from custom post type.
Using multilingual module I could translate all nodes. except the view.
any way in how to achieve this?

I followed this answer but i cant make it work [how do i translate a view page title](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/189872/how-do-i-translate-a-view-page-title)

Steps I used:

1. I have 3 products so I translated each product by clicking the button translate. [image]
2. I have set the filter in view to select based on selected language.
   [image]

with the steps I used I can't get the translated products

I have done some debuging and I found the issue is because relationship is linked using `revision_id` not `id`

Here is the query that I found

```
SELECT * FROM node_field_data
LEFT JOIN node__field_product_overview ON node_field_data.nid = node__field_product_overview.entity_id AND (node__field_product_overview.deleted = '0' AND node__field_product_overview.langcode = node_field_data.langcode)
INNER JOIN paragraphs_item_field_data ON node__field_product_overview.field_product_overview_target_revision_id = paragraphs_item_field_data.revision_id
WHERE (node_field_data.status = '1') AND (node_field_data.type IN ('product')))
```

see this:
`node__field_product_overview.field_product_overview_target_revision_id = paragraphs_item_field_data.revision_id`

is there way to modify query to use `target_id` instead

Comment: anyone around have any idea about this?

Comment: try to install this module : i18nviews

Comment: dont have for drupal 8

Comment: Can you remove Content: Translation language in filter criteria and add Content: Language

Comment: I removed that but I only get the english products

Comment: translated products aren't selected

Comment: Ok, so you translate already translate the product but still showing in English,
Did you translate the content or the product. 
Check this link it will help you with the translation
https://docs.drupalcommerce.org/commerce2/developer-guide/products/product-architecture/multilingual-products

Comment: I have followed this but I can't get the translated products in my view

Comment: Something is strange did you try to clear the cache ?
Did you check if the translation is working fine ( try to access to the translated content)
Technically, after you translate your content type ( Product display ) and you filter by Content language it should work fine

Comment: The translated content is working. But in view is not selected

Comment: in views fields try to search for translated field, Exp : Product Link (Translated)

Comment: now the english products are not selected and translated products are selected

Comment: So it's working fine now ?

Comment: i found this table `paragraphs_item_field_data` doesnt create new paragraph for translation

Comment: is it normal that relationship field is linked using `revision_id` not `id`

Comment: Actually it should not, Revision id is for : 
Every content (node) in Drupal may has some revisions. Suppose you already posted a content in your Drupal site. After saving this content, you have to edit it. You can check "Create a new revision" check box to edit this content without losing old content. So every revision of a single content has a revision ID. You also could make older or newer revision of that content as default.

Comment: @Baach How to change the query?